# Unable to ssh to a Ubuntu 16.04 host after installing xfce Desktop

Tags: xfce

Installed Xfce Desktop on a Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop so that we could use RDP from our Windows laptop to it. While we the remote Desktop worked we failed to ssh to the Ubuntu Desktop from a putty client. The ssh session gets terminated immediately once the username and password is verified.

We tried to do a

$ sudo apt-get purge openssh-server and 
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server

but the above issue remained. Before installing Xfce Desktop we were able ssh into the Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: what about `ufw` status? Does it allow port 22?

Comment: If the session is being terminated *after* authentication, likely it's because something is causing the user's login shell to exit - did you make any changes to their .profile / .bashrc / default shell (`chsh` for example)?

Comment: @z3phyr I have disabled the ufw and tried, still no luck.

Comment: @steeldriver I have only updated the PATH variable (with export PATH) in the .bashrc file.